# Is this a bad way of making flutter app ui responsive?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am new to app development and i am working on my first app using flutter, I find it really frustrating trying to position and size everything on the screen by using alot of different layouts inside each other like columns, rows, containers, etc just to put a picture or a button on the screen with the size and position required by the ui design. However, i found myself very comfortable with using only one stack and positioning everything inside it with the positioned widget and giving everything the coordinates i want.

Also to make the ui responsive on all screen sizes, i came out with a way of multiplying all horizontal sizes and positions with `MediaQuery.of(context)/(width of the screen i am currently testing on)` and the verticals with `MediaQuery.of(context)/(height)`, which worked fine with me in the few screen sizes that i tested on

In all the tutorials I've watched i found no one doing what I'm doing so i just wanted to make sure if this is a bad or unprofessional way to do it, or if there are certain cases where this would not be good.

Also, are there any builders i can use for flutter apps ? and is it ok to use them or is coding everything myself better ?

Here is a sample of an opening page i made with login and sign up buttons to give you an example of what i'm trying to describe:

```
    class opening extends StatelessWidget {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final mq = MediaQuery.of(context);


    final loginButton = MaterialButton(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(62, 59, 73, 1),
        minWidth: 195*mq.size.width/392.7,
        height: 45*mq.size.height/759.3,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25*mq.size.width/392.7),),
       
        child: AutoSizeText('LOGIN',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle( fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontSize: 14*mq.size.width/392.7, color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 248, 248, 3), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Approutes.authLogin);
        },
      );

    final signupButton = ButtonTheme(
        minWidth: 195*mq.size.width/392.7,
        height: 45*mq.size.height/759.3,
      child: OutlineButton(
        highlightedBorderColor:Color.fromRGBO(190, 75, 75, 1) ,
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(190, 75, 75, 1),width: 3.3*mq.size.width/392.7 ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25*mq.size.width/392.7)),
       
        child: AutoSizeText('SIGN UP',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle( fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontSize: 14*mq.size.width/392.7, color: Color.fromRGBO(190, 75, 75, 1),  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Approutes.authRegister);
        },
      )
    );




    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 248, 248, 1),
        body: Stack(
        children: [

           Positioned(child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png' , width: 215*mq.size.width/392.7, fit: BoxFit.contain,),
           top: 230*mq.size.height/759.3, left: 91.35*mq.size.width/392.7,),


          Positioned(child:loginButton ,top: 470*mq.size.height/759.3,left: 100*mq.size.width/392.7,),
          Positioned(child:signupButton ,top: 535*mq.size.height/759.3,left: 100*mq.size.width/392.7,),


        ],
      )


    );



  }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is correct.
For example, in my project, i've got this class where i prepare some functions to find out size of the device and calculationg it with entered values.

```
class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;
  static double defaultSize;
  static Orientation orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}

// Get the proportionate height as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenHeight(double inputHeight) {
  double screenHeight = SizeConfig.screenHeight;
  // 812 is the layout height that designer use
  return (inputHeight / 812.0) * screenHeight;
}

// Get the proportionate height as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenWidth(double inputWidth) {
  double screenWidth = SizeConfig.screenWidth;
  // 375 is the layout width that designer use
  return (inputWidth / 375.0) * screenWidth;
}
```

You can use it too, if you want.
Speaking of some flutter builder, i don´t know about any. In my opinion is better to code it  yourself.

Comment: what about using only a stack and only positioned widgets to put everything on the screen, is it okay? or is using many layout widgets like rows inside columns with alot of paddings in between etc  better in any way ?

Answer (score 0):

Although this might work, it's very tedious to take this approach for making your UI responsive. Moreover, it would also be very difficult to maintain such code if you were to change the UI.

If in the future, someone else is going to work on this project, it's going to be a very hard time for her/him.

Working with UI in Flutter does have a steep learning curve. However, once you get used to it, it will be much easier as compared to working with absolute positions.